# Limitation on defining stylesheet in reactjs native version

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-native

If I try to define a `textalign` with `justify` value in `reactjs native`, I get the error message that only four values are supported: auto, left, right, center. Is it possible to work around this, and define `textalign` with `justify`? Below is the sample code:

```
var styleTest = StyleSheet.create({

 title: {
   fontSize : 20,
   color : 'rgb(0,0,255)',
   textAlign: "justify"
  }

});
```

Just to clarify, I see this when trying out `reactjs native` for `ios`, not in `reactjs`.

The above error happens when calling `StyleSheet.create` method which calls `StyleSheetValidation.validateStyle` method. I guess in order to create a non-supported CSS property, I have to do a workaround and call CSS directly. I am curious how to go about including other stylesheet properties that are not supported, in a simple way. I couldn't find documentation on this. Pointers will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to do a workaround and call CSS directly

It's not actually CSS, it's a description of how it should look using the terms you know from CSS.  The actual implementation does a bunch of math and then conveys it to UIKit in a way it understands, similar to how browsers implement CSS.

This has been done from scratch for react-native.  It's not using an existing css engine.

> I am curious how to go about including other stylesheet properties that are not supported, **in a simple way**

As you may have guessed by the words 'math' and 'UIKit', there's no simple way to do this, and absolutely no way to do it without modifying the objc code.

I suggest [creating an issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/new) or sending a pull request if it's missing something.  Not all of CSS will be supported.

<sub>Disclaimer: Minimal iOS/react-native experience, I don't know what's required to add text justification.  It may be simple.</sub>